# get folders of a folder in one drive pro (sharepoint) rest api

Tags: rest, sharepoint, onedrive

I am trying to get a list of folders underneath my documents folder using the sharepoint rest api. This seems like it should be very simple but I am having a hard time seeing how to do this from the documentation.

I want to determine if the following folder exists:

**[https]://[Site]/personal/[Path to User]/Documents/test**

I tried:

**[https]://[Site]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Documents')**

gives 'file not found', I would expect to get some json returned that gives me file information etc, how do I determine if the /Documents/test folder has been created with the rest api?

Answer (score 0):

Please check it your url is valid like and check the url of your document library :

```
[https]://[Site]/Documents
```

In your case it should be like, if its Documents library:

```
[https]://[Site]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents')
```

Or Write full relative path of your URL like

```
[https]://[Site]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/personal/[Path to User]/Documents/test')
```

Comment: I can make a request to this endpoint: [https]://[Site]/_api/web/folders and get back info but I can't get anything even with something as simple as [https]://[Site]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/personal'), I get file not found exceptions for all of these, including [https]://[Site]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents')

Comment: Are you able to login to site on same browser with same credentials? Did you try [https]://[Site]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(personal/[Path to User]/Documents');

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try it like this:

**[https]://[Site]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents')/folders**

This should give a list of all of the folder underneath your documents library.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfolderbyserverrelativeurl.Aspx) accepts `serverRelativeUrl` parameter that specifies the *server-relative URL for the folder*.

Examples

For location:

```
[https]://[Site]/personal/[Path to User]/Documents
```

the following REST requests return folder object:

```
[https]://[Site]/personal/[Path to User]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/personal/[Path to User]/Documents')
```

or

```
[https]://[Site]/personal/[Path to User]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents')
```

> Note: relative Url to Documents library is specified (not starts with `/` like in your example)